# transfer sepolia faucet using an API

Tags: ethereum

I am working on a functionality that creates wallets for users and fund them with some sepolia faucet for a transaction-
is there any api that I can use to transfer sepolia?

Comment: As this question is not about programming, a better place to ask this would be ethereum.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use a any tool that mine your own
[sepoliaPOW faucet](https://sepolia-faucet.pk910.de/)

that example is only but you can download on a github repo and run it in your machine

It takes time but it should work with more certainty

Other wise try chainlink faucet, usually it work better then the one from infura